# How to bind left + right mouse to middle mouse click emulation in lubuntu?

Tags: xfce, lxde

In xubuntu (xfce desktop) if the left and right mouse buttons are pressed simultaneously, then a middle mouse button click is emulated.

Can this be setup to work in lubuntu? (lxde desktop environment)

Comment: What happens for you in Lubuntu when you press both simultaneously? And what is your version of Lubuntu?

Comment: Press both is currently whichever button was pressed first. Version 16.04